# NSArray atomfeed and categories

Tags: objective-c, arrays, iphone, nsxmlparser, atom-feed

I have an atomfeed with which is succesfully getting parsed. All the articles are in the root array.
But now I also have categories as a tag in the feed.

How can I parse the atom xml so that the root array contains the categories and each category filters to an array with the corresponding articles.

Thanks,
Bing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an `NSArray` (you didn't say of what, so I'll assume `NSDictionary`) of Atom feed items, each of which has a category. What you want is a structure that groups the items by category into `NSArray`s.

The appropriate data structure, in my opinion, is an `NSDictionary` that maps categories onto arrays of items. Here's how I would do it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *itemsByCategory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *item in allItems) {
    NSString *category = [item objectForKey:@"category"];
    NSMutableArray *categoryItems = [itemsByCategory objectForKey:category]; // You'll probably want to do some checking in case there is no category.

    if (!categoryItems) {
        categoryItems = [NSMutableArray array];
        [itemsByCategory setObject:categoryItems forKey:category];
    }

    [categoryItems addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: One more question,
I now have a table view with the categories, is there a way to reuse this tableview with the category result items.

I have been trying in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to create a new table view with the results.

Thank you
Bing